# Whole PC Running Slow

Tags: windows

It feels like my entire computer is running slowly all of a sudden. In an attempt to fix it I reinstalled windows and it was the fastest its ever been for about a day and then went back to "normal." Its to the point where it feels like loading almost anything is unbearably slow. Games that used to load perfectly fine are nearly unplayable. I'm wondering if there's anything obvious that could be done. Thanks!

System Information:

Alienware Laptop

Windows 10

Intel Core i7

NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060

[task manager as of writing this post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwvyY.png)

[image]

Comment: What kind of drive is your C drive and how much free space do you have left? In case of an SSD, they can make your pc go really slow if you have less than 25% of free space left on the drive, as TRIM won't work correctly anymore. The exact point differs per drive, but 25% is a safe value.

Comment: Also, since you reinstalled Windows 10, there are doubtless **many** updates pending. Wait until all updates are completed, and if you need space, use SFC and DISM to reset base.